Wrong computation of sum in a constant expression
My program after porting to Visual Studio shows some weird results. After reduction I came to this minimal reproducible example:
consteval auto operator +( auto x, auto&& y ) {
    return x += y;
}

struct S {
    constexpr operator float() { return 1; }
};

int main() {
    return 0 + S{};
}

I expected it to return 1, but in Visual Studio it returns just an arbitrary number 3422303056, and the assembly code suggests that this value is computed during constant evaluation:
main    PROC
        mov     eax, 1610363728                     ; 5ffc3350H
        ret     0
main    ENDP

Online demo: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/j7eY4qM1s
is the program somehow illformed?

I'm inclined to say that re-implementing int + float is ill-formed or worse.

You can wrap into static_assert to really see msvc failure Demo

@DrewDormann: even without redefining int+float, the issue remains Demo.

0.f + S{} works though Demo

return x += 1.f; also fails - live - https://godbolt.org/z/rs9qK53xY - my vote is MSVC bug.

With the enabled optimizations you will get better assemblers for other but msvc compilers https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/7Trxo5s1h

It seems the consteval (or constexpr) on operator+ is what messes it up for MSVC. Remove that and it'll do the right thing. It sort of looks like it's adding the float bit pattern as-if it was the pattern of an int - but it's not consistent.

It seems to be an issue with MSVC.
If you do:
struct S { constexpr operator int() { return 1; } };
OR
return 0.0 + S{}
You get the expected answer from MSVC

There are no surprising C++ rules that would be relevant here.
Overload resolution and constant expression evaluation should behave here as naively expected and the program should return 1.
Seems to be a MSVC bug.
(Technically I suppose float is not required to be able to represent 1 exactly per C++ standard. In that case the result may be different. But that is not the case here where a IEEE 754 floating point implementation is used.)
